# textboxes not dynamically updating properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, setattribute

Here is how I create the textbox:

```
box = document.createElement("input");
```

Here is how I change the text:

```
box.setAttribute('value',myString);
```

However, each text-box **becomes permanently unresponsive** to the above code does **after I edit it** (in firefox, even clicking on it causes this).

Also, I would like to prevent the user form editing the value sometimes:

```
box.setAttribute('readonly','true');
```

But this also causes the boxes to lock permanently from the program trying to edit them; box.setAttribute('readonly','false') doesn't undo the lock.

Comment: The attribute value refers to what would appear as an attribute inside of the tag, i.e. `<input type="text" value="hello" />`. This has the effect of prepopulating the value of the field on page load - this has no effect on an input which has had its value modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `box.value = myString` and `box.readOnly = false`. Node attributes are always strings and if you want to remove one you need to use `element.removeAttribute('atribute_name')`.

Comment: I don't understand why your way works and mine doesn't, but it does.

Comment: With `box.value` you are setting a property of the node and `setAttribute` you are setting an attribute. The two are very different things. I'm not really sure why the second method doesn't always work (I have accepted it as one of the many weirdness-es of the DOM).

Answer (score 1):

To remove readonly property you must use `box.removeAttribute('readonly');`